# How to get text of drop downlist using javascript ClientID

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview inside a Update Panel which there is a dropdownList .
I want to access value selected item for validation purpose but getting error.

I once managed to get it work correctly by first getting id of gridview in which the drop down list is present and than suffixing it with dropdownList clientID but lost it and now seem unable to get it done.

I get the clientId of the drop down list from viewing HTML source code generated.

`('<%= drpLstId.ClientID %>` gives me error *drpLstId doesn't exist in current context*.

This is the HTML generated for drop down list after the aspx page is generated.

```
<select name="ctl00$viewMain$grdView$ctl01$ddlNew" id="ctl00_viewMain_grdView_ctl01_ddlNew" class="ddl" style="width:70px;">
        <option value="0">Select</option>
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 3</option>
            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
 </select>
```

This is what I have done

```
 function validate()
    {
      var drpDownList= document.getElementById('ctl00_viewMain_grdView_ctl01_ddlNew');
       var drpDownListValue = drpDownList.options[drpDownList.selectedIndex].Text;

       alert(drpDownListValue );

    }
```

But this gives me error `undefined` in alert box

Comment: what is this tonality? it should be ----drpDownList.options[drpDownList.SelectedIndex].Text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `innerHtml` instead of text like:

```
var drpDownListValue = drpDownList.options[drpDownList.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get the control ID by registering js code from serverside

```
RegisterStartupScript("var drpDownList = " + drpLstId.ClientId);
```

and then on client side you can get the inner HTML

var drpDownListValue = drpDownList.options[drpDownList.selectedIndex].innerHTML;

Looking into HTML and getting the client id and then hardcoding that into your code doesn't seems to be a good idea.

Comment: I know the syntex of RegisterStartupScript is not correct as I dont have it handy with me rite now.